# How to setup Karma and Jasmine unit-testing for common js library?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am developing a browser-based JavaScript library. For that purpose, I have set up a directory structure where each module is in a separate file and the final build is generated using webpack in a single file that is to be included in the web-page.

I want to set up a unit testing environment similar to Angular's Karma + Jasmine testing setup where I can write test cases for each module in a separate file and run a single command to execute these tests. Any testing setup is fine as long as a single command is enough to run all the tests and they can be kept in separate files.

The intended structure is something like this:

```
src
  index.js
  index.test.js
  my-module
    index.js
    index.test.js
```

I have looked into mocha's browser testing as I am somewhat familiar with mocha + expect testing for NodeJs but it seems like I have to include each file separately in the testing HTML file.

---

The main goal here is to keep the tests file near the files they are supposed to test as is the case in Angular so that they are easy to maintain and have a single command to run all the tests. The tests must run in a browser similar to how testing works in Angular.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a answer yet. But apparently comments dont let me format correctly. 
Can you please post the intended project structure first ?

I am guessing this is what you dont wish to do ?

```
   project root: /
       package.jsonspec
       --> jasmine_examples
   src/
       module_a
       module_b
       module_c
  test/
      module_a
      module_b
      module_c
```

Because this can easily be made to run all tests by specifying in the jasmine config file this text:

> "spec_files": [
>    "test/**/*.spec.js"]

Comment: The project structure is similar to what kontrollanten mentioned in his answer. I'll update the question.